# Using Basic Auth with loopback.js and ldap

Tags: node.js, passport.js, loopbackjs

I'd like to implement the following scenario:

1. expose Rest-API with loopback
2. Authenticate user using basic auth when accessing the API
3. Validate the credential of the user against an LDAP
4. Fetch from the same LDAP the group to which the user belongs and map it to a user role
5. Use this role with ACL in loopback

All steps taken one by one are "relatively easy" but combining all of them is the tricky part for me here ... because I can see how to do the authentication with a "form based" login for step 2 & 3 using loopback-component-passport and then implementing a role-resolver for step 4 but I'm struggling on how to implement 2, 3 & 4 if 2 is based on Basic Auth.

Any ideas or hints are welcome.
Thanks.